# Want to split the JSON from the URL not the response

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to split the json part from this URL in my iPhone application.

**http://vkontakte.ru/login_success.html#session={"expire":"1272008089","mid":"100172","secret":"9c8d8f0305","sid":"1131703552161ae352a1256402e3140d7cbde41b1602a93d15472c82"}**

I tried and and saved the JSON into a NSString but what i am getting is

**http://vkontakte.ru/api/login_success.html?session=%7B%22mid%22:113158415,%22secret%22:%227ce58bfcd3%22,%22sid%22:%2203831b43c1bb992f9477efbfe96e83f6ecff1c1b661315ac0a20719cf57a44%22,%22expire%22:0%7D**

This is not coming in JSOn Format. Below is my code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSError* error;
    NSLog (@"json path %@",url);
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *json_string = [url absoluteString];
    NSArray *arr = [json_string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    json_string = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
        // parse the JSON response into an object
        // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
    NSArray *statuses = [json_string JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",error);

        // Each element in statuses is a single status
        // represented as a NSDictionary
        for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
        {
            // You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary
            // This will print the tweet and username to the console
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"secret "], [[status objectForKey:@"mid"] objectForKey:@"sid"]);
        }
        return YES;
}
```

How can move further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

`NSString *json_string = [url absoluteString];`

with

`NSString *json_string = [[url absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.

That's a really strange thing you're doing, though. Why does the URL have JSON in it?

Comment: I am trying Sharing in Vkontakte they give the secret key in this URL